# Why does the location of the SUM() in an IF statement matter in a GROUP BY scenario when the grouped by column is changed? (BigQuery)?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, sql-execution-plan, order-of-execution

I have some electrical meter data that I want to group by meter and convert all data to baseline units. The below query does that:

```
SELECT meter, 
   IF(unit="kWh" OR unit="kW", "kW", IF(unit="kVAr" OR unit="kVArh", "kVAr", NULL)) as unit,
   SUM(IF(unit="kWh" OR unit="kVArh", value*2, value)) as value,     

FROM data_sample
GROUP BY meter, unit
```

However, if I change the second line to `IF(unit="kWh" OR unit="kVArh", SUM(value*2), SUM(value)) as value`, in other words if I move the SUM() inside the IF statement, I get an error: "*SELECT list expression references column unit which is neither grouped nor aggregated*"

The weird thing is, if I remove the unit's IF statement, e.g.

```
SELECT 
   meter, unit,
   SUM(IF(unit="kWh" OR unit="kVArh", value*2, value)) as value,
   IF(unit="kWh" OR unit="kVArh", SUM(value*2), SUM(value)) as value2,
   
FROM data_sample
GROUP BY meter, unit
```

Then it works, giving the same result for value and value2. I don't understand why this is the case, I assume it has something to do with the order of processing? If someone could help me understand this please.

Example data:

```
WITH data_sample AS (
   SELECT "m1" as meter, "kWh" as unit, 2 as value UNION ALL 
   SELECT "m1" as meter, "kWh" as unit, 3 as value, UNION ALL 
   SELECT "m1" as meter, "kVArh" as unit, 5 as value, UNION ALL
   SELECT "m1" as meter, "kW" as unit, 5 as value UNION ALL
   SELECT "m2" as meter, "kWh" as unit, 4 as value UNION ALL
   SELECT "m2" as meter, "kW" as unit, 6 as value UNION ALL 
   SELECT "m3" as meter, "kW" as unit, 4 as value UNION ALL
   SELECT "m3" as meter, "kVAr" as unit, 4 as value )
```

Example data (generated by code above)

[image]

Desired Output (generated by first code snippet):

[image]

(In other words it groups the data by unit. If the unit of the considered group is either kWh or kVarh (ie with an "h") it converts the value to kW and kVar (without an "h") respectively by multiplying with 2 and renames the unit accordingly before summing all the kW and kVAr values for each meter)

Comment: If you sum over the whole table, there is no information about the unit anymore. Therefore you cannot access in an `if` anymore.  `SUM(value*2), SUM(value)`  will never work for different units. Think of you have 1$ and 10 cents OR 10$ and 1 cent. If you sum it up without looking on the unit, you end up with 11 in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Samuel mentioned in comments:

If you sum over the whole table, there is no information about the unit anymore. Therefore you cannot access in an if anymore. `SUM(value*2)`, `SUM(value)` will never work for different units. Think of you have **1$** and **10 cents** OR **10$** and **1 cent**.

If you sum it up without looking on the unit, you end up with 11 in both cases.

Posting the answer as *community wiki* since this clearly explains the concern of OP and for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.

Comment: I see what you are saying, I would like to add that I also realised that the grouping was being done on the "recreated" unit column (ie the one in which they are renamed) not the original unit column; while the IF statements are using the original unit column. This means that SUM(IF..) works because it ia aggregated over the new group, while IF(..SUM()) doesn't work because the if statement is looking at the original units which aren't aggregated over the new group.